# My SQL Command Isn't Properly Ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble trying to find out where the error would be here. From what I can tell everything looks correct:

```
SELECT  a.department_name
FROM department a
OUTER JOIN (SELECT department_id, 
            NVL((TO_CHAR(MAX(salary + commission)), '$9,990.00'), '$0.00') as "Maximum Total Pay",
            NVL((TO_CHAR(MAX(hire_date)), 'DD-MON-YYYY'), '01-JAN-3000') as "Maximum Hire Date",
            NVL((TO_CHAR(MIN(hire_date)), 'DD-MON-YYYY'), '01-JAN-3000') as "Minimum Hire Date",
            COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES
            FROM employee c
            WHERE employee_id IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY c.department_id)
ON          a.department_id = c.department_id  
ORDER BY    a.department_name;
```

I am getting the error that the SQL Command Not Properly Ended. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: I can't select two correct answers as both of these helped me get to the right solution. Thank you to all who helped.

Comment: But you could **upvote** both answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, null values may come from your subquery, but not from department, so use `LEFT` OUTER JOIN.

But the main problem is due to paranthesis for

`NVL((TO_CHAR(MAX(hire_date)), 'DD-MON-YYYY'), '01-JAN-3000')` statements,

*For both use :*

`NVL(TO_CHAR(MAX(hire_date), 'DD-MON-YYYY'), '01-JAN-3000')` instead, by removing 1st and 5th paranthesis from left.

Comment: Thank you @barbaros, this helped clean up the errors!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to alias your subquery in which you are joining to, and add the keyword `LEFT`:

```
SELECT  a.department_name
FROM department a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT department_id, 
            NVL((TO_CHAR(MAX(salary + commission)), '$9,990.00'), '$0.00') as "Maximum Total Pay",
            NVL((TO_CHAR(MAX(hire_date)), 'DD-MON-YYYY'), '01-JAN-3000') as "Maximum Hire Date",
            NVL((TO_CHAR(MIN(hire_date)), 'DD-MON-YYYY'), '01-JAN-3000') as "Minimum Hire Date",
            COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES
            FROM employee c
            WHERE employee_id IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY c.department_id) c1
ON          a.department_id = c1.department_id  
ORDER BY    a.department_name;
```

I called it `c1` just so you can notice the alias.

Comment: I updated it with your addition in Oracle and it is still coming back with the same error on the OUTER JOIN line.

Comment: Saw the update adding the word 'LEFT' but am now receiving an error saying I am missing a right parenthesis in the line below the join, I even copied the full code above. I have reviewed both sets and the look exactly alike. Could it be an error with the system?

Comment: Maybe you're also looking for NVL2 function and not NVL?  NVL only supports 2 arguments and you're passing 3.  Thanks for the edit @jon-heller